# Tankless hot water system only providing luke-warm water?

Tags: hot-water, tankless

I have tankless hot water which has been working well up until this week.  A week ago we discovered a leak on the hose from the propane tank, so we replaced the hose, but since then it hasn't seemed to want to heat the water much.

Most days it warms the water to around 25-30 degrees Celcius, and takes a few tries of turning the water on/off over a few minutes before it finally decides to actually get going and heats the water properly.

But this morning we haven't been able to get it going - it warms to around 26C, which is noticeably warmer than the cold water (so it's definitely doing something), but not too comfortable for a shower!

[image]

Now I'm not a DIY/Home-Improvement guy, but we live in a place where it's difficult to get someone in to take a look, so I'm wondering if this is something that's common or easy to fix, or a known problem?

The gas tank is full and fully open, and I've adjusted the dial on the system to extremes (photo shows where we usually have it set).

Comment: How long has the unit been in service? Is there a good flow rate of water from the hot or is the flow rate reduced from when the heater was working properly?

Comment: @JimStewart it's about 1.5-2 years I guess. Yes good flow of water, same as before.

Comment: I'm going to replace the battery to see if that helps

Comment: Sounds like a sticky mixing valve (too much cold added to the heated water before going to the output) might be at fault.  The replaced propane line is a red herring here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Do you mean at the heater?  Or in the bathroom?  The water temp is the same no matter which tap I use in the house, and the read-out on the heater says 26C (normally when at temperature it reads much higher, but currently it's not going over 25-30)

Comment: If the electronics are powered by a battery only, then that is a good bet as the cause.

Comment: Since the problem occurred when you replaced the gas hose, I'm going to suspect something to do with that replacement - new hose smaller than old hose, valve not fully open, debris in the system - not getting full gas supply.